# If a flag is raised on a question that is then deleted, should that be held against the flag raiser?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I refer to my flag raised for the asker of this question:

https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/137476/what-sources-of-food-can-be-found-in-mountainous-terrain

asked 23 hours ago by [Albert tyson](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/60679/albert-tyson)

My flag for moderator's attention is worded thus (excuse typing spelling):

> The question is fine. If you look at this guy's account, he has
>   created a new on as he apears to have lost the login to the old one he
>   used earlier today. " accounts, not within the rules, this guy is
>   genuine and just trying to create a world and could do with mod help
>   to amalgamate the accounts. – Fay Suggers

I recieve this:

> 23 hours ago   declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no
>   evidence to support it

You will observe that the question has been deleted, and (assuming some access to data that I don't possess) that the accounts of **Albert tyson** and **Albert Tyson** have been amalgamated and are now [Albert tyson](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/60679/albert-tyson) (Of course if you glance at his profile you will see his testimony of support for my story - even without the godlike powers of mods).

This adds to my "flags declined" total - Perhaps the mod responsible for reviewing my request assuming that my flag was malicious or deranged (going by my typing - not unreasonably). If mods are not able to see any appropriate history, then how can they assume otherwise. Is this a feature or a bug?

Comment: The merge happened ten minutes after your flag.  I'm going to guess that the mod who handled the flag didn't notice that, saw an account that didn't seem to need attention, and declined, but that's a guess.  That said, don't worry too much about one declined flag; it takes more than that before the system starts issuing you warnings (and more than *that* before you hit temporary blocks).  I occasionally fat-finger comment flags because of the way the UI is laid out and I always feel bad when that happens, but so long as it's infrequent it doesn't cause damage (just confusion sometimes).

Comment: @Monica Cellio It concerns me because a menu (that I don't know what it's called) which was available to me when I began editing, it no longer available. I would ask a question about it, but I'm new here and don't know how to approach this - especially considering I'm not familiar with the names of anything. Was one of the mod's tools "flashed" inadvertantly to us plebs about 3 weeks ago, or what's going on?

Comment: I appreciate your efforts to help moderate the site, and I hope I didn't come across as discouraging you from flagging!  We were all new once and the tools can be a little confusing sometimes.  I *think* you saw a warning along the lines of "your last flag was declined so please be careful" or something similar.  As far as I can tell, you are not blocked from flagging.  The system is trying to help you but, being a mindless piece of code, it can't always tell what help you need.  For this particular flag, we'll need to wait for the mod who handled it to weigh in.

Comment: @Monica Cellio I understand what you're saying, you are entirely correct. There is something else going on which is most disconcerting and irrational however, I've no idea what it means.

Comment: [It seems there are no serious consequences having a high(er) declined flag count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135105/what-are-the-bad-things-if-any-associated-with-the-declined-flag-count)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am the one who handled your flag. As Monica Cellio correctly guessed, when I checked the two users your flag was referring to, I found just one and therefore declined the flag.

I didn't take any other action, and as far as I can tell, you are just being warned when flagging, there is no ban on your profile.  To quote Monica: The system is trying to help you but, being a mindless piece of code, it can't always tell what help you need.

If you can try to provide more details on what you are missing, we can try to give a look into it.

Comment: Thanks @L.Dutch For now I'll just keep studying the system to figure out what it was - it could just be a stray bit of code my old browser flashed at me. I'll get round to  updating my system to eliminate that factor too.